# How to define right-triangle in tikz as a node

Tags: tikz-styles

To get an equilateral triangle I use

```
\tikzstyle{triangle} = [fill=green!20, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3]
```

But I am struggling with defining tikz node for right angle triangle

I thought of doing something like this

```
\tikzstyle{anytriangle} = [draw, A--B--C--A]
```

and then

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[ auto, node distance=4em]

% Gridline
\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,4);

\node [anytriangle] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I get an error: unknown coordinate A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this (but I have to admit that I do not fully understand what you want to achieve):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{triangle/.append style={fill=green!20, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3},
         anytriangle/.append style={draw, append after command={ \pgfextra{ \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (A); } }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=4em]

% Gridline
\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (0,4);

\node [anytriangle] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: almost right. But why there is a square around right angle ?

Comment: This is the border of the node. I wasn’t sure what exactly you wanted to achieve. Just delete the `draw` option from anytriangle. But why do you need a node anyways? In this case, any node will draw the same triangle. But I guess this is not what you wanted?

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `isosceles triangle` shape with `apex angle=90`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    right angle triangle/.style={
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=90},
    every node/.style={right angle triangle, 
        draw, inner sep=0pt,
        anchor=left corner,
        shape border rotate=90},
    paint/.style={draw=#1!75, fill=#1!20}
    ]


\draw[help lines] grid (5,2);

\foreach \a/\c in {1.5/blue, 1/green, 0.5/red}{
    \node[paint=\c, minimum width=\a cm] at (0,0) {};
    \node[paint=\c, minimum height=\a cm] at (2,0) {};
    }

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm,
    every node/.style={
        right angle triangle,
        isosceles triangle stretches=false,
        draw, inner sep=0pt,
        minimum height=1cm,
        anchor=apex}
    ]
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\foreach \a/\c in {45/blue, 135/green,225/red,315/orange}
     \node[paint=\c, 
        shape border rotate=\a] at (1,1) {};

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

from your question i understood, that you looking for this:

[image]

i labeled coordinates A, B and C by pins (that you can see, that trianlge perfectly match with it.

for above images i suggest two solutions:

- use isosceles triangle (similar to [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi) answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
trian/.style = {isosceles triangle,
     isosceles triangle apex angle=90,
     minimum size=4cm/sqrt(2), inner sep=0pt,
     anchor=east,rotate=-135,
     draw, fill=green!20}
                        ]
\coordinate[pin=below:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[pin=below:B] (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate[pin=C]       (C) at (0,4);
%
\node [trian] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- with small picture (`\pic`), which is not nodes, but has similar features (from possible nodes anchors I define only three corners as `-a`, `-b` and ˙-c`):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
trian/.pic = {
    \draw [fill=green!20]
        (0,0) coordinate (-a) --
        (4,0) coordinate (-b) --
        (0,4) coordinate (-c) -- cycle;
            }
                        ]
\coordinate[pin=below:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[pin=below:B] (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate[pin=C]       (C) at (0,4);
%
\pic[above right] at (A) {trian};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in both cases the result is the same